# Copy to the first empty line after C6

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy from an order sheet to the Log 2018 sheet.
The spreadsheet has already been opened and I will make it active.
The first line to copy is line 6. Column C will always have data.

I would like to find the next empty column from C6.

```vb
Windows("Log 2018").Active
Sheets("Log 2018").Range("C6").End(xlDown).Offset(1,-1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
indows("Order Sheet.xls".Active
Sheets("Order Input").Range("E4".Cells.PastgeSpecial xlAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

The second line highlights and shows

> application and object defined error

Comment: `PastgeSpecial`? Should that be `PasteSpecial`? In fact, this whole line has some issues - `"E4".Cells.PastgeSpecial` is definitely invalid syntax... are you trying to paste to `Range("E4")`?

Comment: I would recommend doing a check of the last row in the column versus the last row down, so that if the xlUp >= the xlDown, you don't write to the cell.  Just something preventative so you don't accidentally write to the final row in the entire sheet when nothing is after C6.

Comment: Should *Sheets("Log 2018").Range("C6").End(xlDown).Offset(1,-1).Select*  be read as *Sheets("Log 2018").Range("B" & Sheets("Log 2018").Range("C6").End(xlDown).Row+1).Copy*?  Verifying as you're copying Cells(LastRow+1,"B") and pasting to E4 and want to ensure that you're getting the correct offset cell.  I believe it would be cleaner if the last row being found was a variable, so you can more easily keep track of what is happening in the single line.

Comment: There's syntax error in `Windows("Order Sheet.xls".Active`

Answer (score 1):

Took me a couple times, but i believe you wrote that the second line is giving you the error.  To fix that would also correct this whole section:

```
Windows("Log 2018").Active
Sheets("Log 2018").Range("C6").End(xlDown).Offset(1,-1).Select 'THIS ONE
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
```

I would recommend the following:

```
'to clean up all of the above code
dim lr as long
with Sheets("Log 2018")
    lr = .cells(6,"C").end(xlDown).Row
    .cells(lr+1,"B").Copy 'Wrote this based on your Offset of -1 col, +1 row
end with
'this would be your current paste from here down
Sheets("Order Input").cells(4,"E").PasteSpecial xlAll
```

Note that you don't need to activate the sheets if you're using them, nor use select to perform operations.